# Duplicate key issue with a Foreign constraint

Tags: postgresql

I have a database with the following tables: `items`, `categories`, and `category_items`. The (simplified, fields omitted) schema is as follows:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS items (
    id SERIAL primary key not null,
    partNo text unique not null
);

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS categories (
    id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
    name TEXT UNIQUE
);

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS category_items (
    category_id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
    partno TEXT NOT NULL,
    FOREIGN KEY (partno) REFERENCES items(partno),
    FOREIGN KEY (category_id) REFERENCES categories(id)
);
```

This schema seems to work fine until I want to insert a record into the `category_items` table. On the first insert to `category_items`, it works, however if I try to insert another item of the same category, I get a duplicate key error: `duplicate key value violates unique constraint "category_items_pkey" Detail: Key (category_id)=(2) already exists.`

The thing is, `category_id` is never specified to have to be unique, so why would this lead to a constraint error?

These are the records I am triyng to insert:

```
INSERT INTO category_items (category_id, partno, size) VALUES
    ((SELECT id FROM categories WHERE name = 'category1'), 'part1', '1"');
    
INSERT INTO category_items (category_id, partno, size) VALUES
    ((SELECT id FROM categories WHERE name = 'category1'), 'part2', '4"');
```

Using PostgreSQL 14. Also if this matters, I am running this on sqlfiddle.com

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two/three problems with the design of the 3rd table:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS category_items (
    category_id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
    partno TEXT NOT NULL,
    FOREIGN KEY (partno) REFERENCES items(partno),
    FOREIGN KEY (category_id) REFERENCES categories(id)
);
```

- `category_id` should not be `SERIAL` in this table as it has a `FOREIGN KEY` constraint to `categories`. Values are auto-created when new rows are inserted into the `categories` table and you need to use those, not create new ones.
- `category_id` should not be the `PRIMARY KEY` of this table, as you may have some category associated with more than one parts.
- You don't need a serial at all in this table as the natural `PRIMARY KEY` is the combination of category and part.

After the above suggestions, the design becomes:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS category_items (
    category_id INT NOT NULL,
    partno TEXT NOT NULL,
    -- other columns, i.e.
    -- size TEXT NOT NULL,   
    PRIMARY KEY (category_id, part_no),
    FOREIGN KEY (partno) REFERENCES items (partno),
    FOREIGN KEY (category_id) REFERENCES categories (id)
);
```

Answer (score 0):

I have figured it's a quite simple fix, I am just feeling a bit silly for missing it. Since in `category_items`, `category_id` is the PRIMARY KEY, it will default to being UNIQUE. I need a separate ID for `category_items` like so:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS category_items (
    id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
    category_id SERIAL NOT NULL,
    partno TEXT NOT NULL,
    size TEXT NOT NULL,
    FOREIGN KEY (partno) REFERENCES items(partno),
    FOREIGN KEY (category_id) REFERENCES categories(id)
);
```